# Parsing Large PDF file using Apache Tika

Tags: java, apache, apache-tika

I am facing some issue while parsing large PDF file using Apache Tika.
File size is close to 5 MB.

Here is the Code:

```
package com.ibm.lnk.processor;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.ibm.lnk.utility.LNKProcessorUtility;

public class TestClient {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream=null;
    try {
         inputStream=new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\CognitiveAssignment\\ProjectSpecificMaterials\\C3Portal\\TestData\\T1\\Anupam Sarkar_IBM_CV.pdf"));
        String content=LNKProcessorUtility.getTextContent(inputStream);
        System.out.println(content);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }finally {
        inputStream.close();
    }
}
}
```

And the Exception I am getting is:

> org.apache.tika.exception.TikaException: Unable to extract all PDF content

Can any one help me on resolving the issue?

Comment: What's the full exception, including stacktrace?

Comment: what TIKA version are you using?

Comment: Could be this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-2098 . Btw you should edit your question to include the stack trace. This would show whether it is the same issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try using apache pdfbox for reading text from pdf

sample code-

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
    import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

    public class PDFTextReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
       File file = new File("<any pdf>");
       PDDocument inputDoc= PDDocument.load(file);   
       PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();        
       System.out.println("Text: " + stripper.getText(inputDoc));  
       }
    }
```